# In Django REST Framework, Using ModelViewSet with renderers,

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using ModelViewSet and struggling to setup a rendering standard. The documentation doesn't show how to use ModelViewSet with drf renderers.
I want the output to be of this format:

```
Format : {'message': <custom message>, 'data': <output from ModelViewSet>}
```

Code:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    renderer_classes = [GenericAPIRenderer]

# How to Override?
class GenericAPIRenderer(renderers.JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works without any issue,

```
class GenericAPIRenderer(renderers.JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        updated_data = {'message': "some custom message", 'data': data}
        return super().render(updated_data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

Comment: How do I pass on a custom message from the view layer?

Comment: if you want to inject the "custom message* from view, then, better override the corresponding methods

Comment: @AshfaqUrRahmanN `renderer_context` seems to be the appropriate place to pass additional information, or add your own parameter

Comment: @IainShelvington It seems he needs to send ***dynamic message*** with each request methods, (for example, one message for HTTP GET, another for HTTP POST, and so on) and in such a situation, I don't think `renderer_context` will do that job

Comment: @ArakkalAbu According to the docs for `renderer_context`: "By default this will include the following keys: view, request, response, args, kwargs.". Seems like it should contain the required data. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#renderer_contextnone

Comment: I wasn't aware of that point, thanks for the info @IainShelvington